# Edição que altera um pouco a resposta original

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, edição, respostas, edições-sugeridas

Na resposta à pergunta [Melhorar visualização do cabeçalho da tabela usando bootstrap 3.0.0, datatables e fixedHeader](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/73235/melhorar-visualiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-cabe%C3%A7alho-da-tabela-usando-bootstrap-3-0-0-datatables) foi feita uma edição que altera um pouco a resposta original. Pareceu-me que foi mesmo intencional o AR colocar mesmo assim a resposta.

Que acham que se deveria fazer? Eu pensei em reverter.

Comment: Eu pessoalmente discordo deste tipo de edição também. Reverter parece o mais correto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu comentei na [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/73235/melhorar-visualiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-cabe%C3%A7alho-da-tabela-usando-bootstrap-3-0-0-datatables#comment150588_73258):

> mesmo estando comentado, talvez o zTop seja algo que funcionou pra ti, mas também pode ser o uso do html que afetou o Z, e neste caso o zTop só funcionaria pra ti

Em outras palavras o `zTop` não foi adicionado a resposta final do autor ou porque ele "esqueceu", ou porque talvez isto resolva somente no seu caso devido ao como foi escrito o html e talvez para outros usuários isto poderia vir a falhar, sendo assim a junção da resposta com o comentário do Gabriel, deve solucionar o seu problema.

No entanto se o Gabriel achar que algo pertinente a qualquer uso então o caminho mais correto é ele adicionar a resposta.

Se o autor da pergunta achar que a nova resposta dele não responde a pergunta, ou não funciona, então acredito que o correto seria comentar, acaso o autor da pergunta ignore ou diga que não vai editar por algum motivo, então o próprio @MarceloDiniz deveria formular uma nova resposta e mencionar que o Gabriel o auxilio em encontrar a resposta (assim penso eu).

Mas nunca editar uma resposta "já pronta", com exceção de correção de grafia e marcação do texto.

Então no caso seria melhor efetuar o "Rollback"

Digo isto como sendo apenas a minha opinião, se a comunidade aceitar que alguns tipos de edições em códigos na resposta pode ser benéfico então eu apoiarei.

Comment: explicado e por que das coisas!!!

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento querias dizer autor da resposta?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento o pior é que a edição foi aprovada...

Comment: @JorgeB. Sim a minha resposta, foi inicialmente em resposta a isto http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4091/3635 ... No entanto o final é destinado a você, ou seja o Rollback é o melhor caminho. Realmente foi aprovado :(

Answer (score 1):

Este e o exemplo inicial dado pelo Marcelo : http://jsbin.com/regetiyaki/1/edit

Se vocês removerem o `zTop`  e adicionarem o "offsetTop": 50 no lugar os três problemas dele serão corrigidos.

Antes de entender que o problema seria esse eu  tinha dado outra solução que é o scroll, porém ele explicou que não era o que ele precisava, então adicionei abaixo a resposta certa dando duas opções, pelo scroll e pelo offsetTop, e como o offsetTop resolveu o problema do Marcelo editei a resposta  para deixar apenas o que resolveu o problema.

Answer (score 0):

Então Jorge, o que eu, como quem fez a pergunta ve:

primeiro o Gabriel tinha dado uma resposta como ideia, dai expliquei que não iria atender e com isso ele editou a resposta, mantendo a ideia que foi boa mas não atendia no caso, e adicionou mais items, e com isso já atendeu parcialmente. Com isso, por comentários, me passou mais uma resposta que dai sim completaria a resposta, fui e editei a resposta, adicionando esse novo item e marquei como válida.
Agora vi que o Gabriel removeu a ideia que tinha passado inicialmente e também removeu o item a mais que realmente serve para validar a resposta, e com isso adicionei esse novo item na resposta.

Espero ter conseguido explicar o fato. Acho que pode manter da forma que editei agora, pois é o que realmente esta servindo a questão.

Comment: Mas se a resposta não lhe serviu, acredito que neste caso seria conversar com o autor. Se neste caso ele "ignora-se" o seu pedido, então você talvez pude-se fazer uma nova resposta e mencionar nela que foi ele quem encontrou ou ajudou a encontrar a resposta (apenas se ele ignora-se, o que não parecia o caso). Acredito que foi um pouco falta de conversa. Acho que alguns comentários seus bastariam :)

Comment: Acredito que um simples item a mais não va mudar em nada, a resposta que esta no momento já atende e é o mais importante, para mim e para outros que possam a ajudar!

Comment: Marcelo veja a minha resposta por favor: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4092/3635

Comment: Mas eu acho que a sua edição não devia ser aprovada porque o autor da resposta refere "voce pode diminuir o zTop para 1020 ou remove-lo que que todas as questões ficam resolvidas" ou seja é intenção dele não colocar o zTop.